# Can't access the website with only one device (PC) which is on and working

Tags: dns, ip, website

Around 2 weeks ago I suddenly became unable to use my university's classroom website from my PC. My PC is the only device having problem, I can freely access it from my phone or laptop. Website url is, classroom.btu.edu.ge. When I try to ping it form my PC it shows IP 188.93.95.169 but from Laptop it shows 104.26.12.198 which is correct one (cause I can access it from laptop). Some time ago I think i edited some dns settings from cmd or something like that, I was having problem and that solved it and I don't know how to reverse/check it if its causing the problem.

Whenever I try to to go to the url it just does nothing in the browser (tried all of them similar result)

(I don't know if I should be asking this question here so if something tell me where to move it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to edit your hosts file then adding the following (of updating any existing entries)

`104.26.12.198 classroom.btu.edu.ge`

If you are on windows, open your notepad as admin then locate the following file
`C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`

This path is usually hidden, so the fastest option would be to open notepad then paste this path in the file-name input box.

Comment: FINALLY, thank you it solved. that's the edit i was talking about I just couldn't find how to reverse.